# Migrate Website Infrastructure to Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure

I have an accessible static HTML website set with domain and hosting. I would like to mimic this environment with Azure, meaning Azure will communicate with my domain and hosting provider.

Could I please ask to point to where should I find answer to this? It seems obvious, but I am not really sure about my search results.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create CNAME record on your domain registrar account

1. Open a new browser tab and sign in to your domain registrar account.
2. Navigate to your domain name's DNS configuration settings.
3. Add a new CNAME record with the following values.

Setting     Value
Type    CNAME
Host    Your subdomain, such as www
Value   Paste the domain name you set aside in the text editor.
TTL (if applicable)     Leave as default value.

Create a CNAME record in Azure Static Web Apps. Please find detailed step by step guide below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain-external